# Open a modal popUp in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I have this button in react:

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>openPopUp(object)}>
                                            Manage Permissions
</button>
```

and when I click the buton I want to open this popUp:

PopUp.js:

```
const PopUp = (props) => {
return (
    <div className="modal fade" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{props.object.name}</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {props.object.permissions.map((permission) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={permission.code}>
                                {permission.name}
                                {props.showDeleteButton(permission.id, props.object.name)}
                                <p> </p>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                    <form onSubmit={e => props.addPermission(e, props.object)}>
                        <label>
                            Insert a permission:
                         <input type="text" value={props.object.value} onChange={props.handleChange} />
                        </label>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

To do that, I did this, but the pop up wont open:

```
 let openPopUp=(object)=>{
    return   <PopUp object={object} cont={cont} onChange={handleChange} addPermission={addPermission} showDeleteButton={showDeleteButton}/>
}
```

There is any error thrown, the popUp just doesn´t open.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `openPopUp` is a onclick handler, it will not return anything to render. To achieve your goal, simply use a state variable with initial value as false, and update that value in `openPopUp` method. Use that bool for conditional rendering of PopUp component.

Like this:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    openPopUp: false,
    object: null
  }
}

openPopUp(object) {
  this.setState({
    openPopUp: true,
    object: object
  })
}


render() {
  return (
    <div>
      ....
      {this.state.openPopUp && 
        <PopUp object={this.state.object} cont={cont} onChange={handleChange} addPermission={addPermission} showDeleteButton={showDeleteButton} />}
      ....
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I cant have a state because this isn´t a component, just a constant

Comment: it will be a functional component, with latest version of react we can use `useState` to define state in functional comp. check the [react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) example. use that and create a bool.

Comment: without state you can not do this. Use react hooks if you dont want to use class component